# Digipak - der, die oder das?

Tags: gender, article

Es handelt sich um die Verpackung einer CD(s).
Die ewige Frage: ist das **der**, **die** oder **das**?

Ich würde **das** sagen, aber Google Translate (und auch Yandex Translate) übersetzen *a damaged Digipak* als *beschädigte Digipak*.

P.S. Auch plural, bitte :)
Die Digipäke oder die Digipaks?

[image: Digipak]

Comment: *Die* CD-Hülle. Alternativ *die* CD-Verpackung. *»Digipak«* werde ich nicht in meinen passiven Wortschatz aufnehmen, geschweige denn in meinen aktiven.

Comment: @Jan in meinem Fall, handelt es sich um eine besondere Terminologie. z.B. Slim-Case, Jewelcase, Single Maxi-Case, Super Jewel Case, Digipak, Papersleeve, Eco-Friendly Case, etc... Die sind alle CD-Verpackungen, aber wie viel von den kennst Du? ;-)

Comment: Die wahre Frage ist doch, wie viele von denen sollte man aus welchen Gründen kennen und welche davon muss man in alltäglichen Situationen benützen. *CD-Hülle, schmälere CD-Hülle, Papierhülle* und *Doppel-CD-Hülle* sind für mich *völlig* ausreichend und (Vorteil!) deskriptiv.

Comment: @Jan, nochmal: *besondere Terminologie*. Gilt zwischen den Sammler. z.B. ist es doch wichtig welche Edition der release/pressing ist gemeint, Digipak oder Jewel-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohne weitere Informationen als jenen aus [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-_und_DVD-Verpackungen), nämlich:

> »Das Digipak ist eine Verpackung zur Aufnahme von einer bis zu acht CDs oder DVDs. Es gilt als hochwertig, ist allerdings anfälliger für Beschädigungen. Digipak ist eine eingetragene Marke der Firma AGI.
>   Digipaks haben meist die gleiche Größe wie das normale Jewelcase, sind aber – bei halber Tiefe – auch bis zum Format einer VHS-Kassette erhältlich.«

kann man schlussfolgern, dass es sich bei *das Digipak* um ein sächliches Nomen handelt, dessen Plural *die Digipaks* ist.

Comment: Right. I should have looked into Wikipedia first. I started with Duden Online and didn't find a Digipak article.

Comment: @c.p.: Ich habe mir erlaubt, deinen Wortanteil in deiner Antwort ins Deutsche zu übersetzen. Wir sind hier in einem Deutsch-Forum, die Frage wurde auf Deutsch gestellt, und du hast einen deutschen Text als Hauptteil deiner Antwort zitiert. Da halte ich es für angebracht, deine eigenen Worte nicht in einer Fremdsprache, sondern ebenfalls in Deutsch niederzuschreiben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Danke. Ich habe gar nicht gemerkt, dass ich auf Englisch beantwortet habe.